# How to automate click on the JNLP download windows while automating login to a web application using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jnlp

I am writing an automation script using the selenium webdriver to login to our web application.
However, after providing the user id and password and clicking on login, I get a JNLP login window for which I need to click OK.
How can I automate this in webdriver?
Any help would be appreciated.

Please find the code I have so far

```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    public class NavigateToUrl {
        public static void main (String[] args){
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://mytestapp");
            WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_0']"));
            username.sendKeys("user1");
            WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_1']"));
            password.sendKeys("Password1");
            WebElement credentialSubmit = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dijit_form_Button_0_label']"));
            credentialSubmit.click();
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VHP5.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of that window ?

Comment: I have added the screenshot above. I need to automate the click on the OK button for the JNLP file.

Comment: Your screenshot does not show a login window but a window of the java webstart and it also provides a "Do this automatically from now on", I don't think there is anything more to "automate" than checking that box ...